# Data augmentation for text classification

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification, data-science, text-classification

What is the current state of the art data augmentation technic about text classification?

I made some research online about how can I extend my training set by doing some data transformation, the same we do on image classification.
I found some interesting ideas such as:

- Synonym Replacement: Randomly choose n words from the sentence that does not stop words. Replace each of these words with one of its synonyms chosen at random.
- Random Insertion: Find a random synonym of a random word in the sentence that is not a stop word. Insert that synonym into a random place in the sentence. Do this n times.
- Random Swap: Randomly choose two words in the sentence and swap their positions. Do this n times.
- Random Deletion: Randomly remove each word in the sentence with probability p.

But nothing about using pre-trained word vector representation model such as word2vec. Is there a reason?

Data augmentation using a word2vec might help the model to get more data based on external information. For instance, replacing a toxic comment token randomly in the sentence by its closer token in a pre-trained vector space trained specifically on external online comments.

Is it a good method or do I miss some important drawbacks of this technic?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of using word2vec embedding usually helps. However, that is a context-free embedding. To go one step further, the state of the art (SOTA) as of today (2019-02) is to use a language model trained on large corpus of text and fine-tune your own classifier with your own training data.

The two SOTA models are:

- GPT-2 https://github.com/openai/gpt-2
- BERT https://github.com/google-research/bert

These data augmentation methods you mentioned might also help (depends on your domain and the number of training examples you have). Some of them are actually used in the language model training (for example, in BERT there is one task to randomly mask out words in a sentence at pre-training time). If I were you I would first adopt a pre-trained model and fine tune your own classifier with your current training data. Taking that as a baseline, you could try each of the data augmentation method you like and see if they really help.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I was wondering what arte the drawbacks of using context free embedding to generate vector based synonym expect the fact that you might potentially have a chance to change the entire meaning of the sentence (even when the new samples don’t make perfect sense to humans, this may not matter too much for the model).

Comment: One draw-back is that for some words that could be ambiguous, (think about bank, which could mean "financial bank" or "river bank"), the learned vector could be biased to largely represent the most popular meaning. If you use the embedding in a short sentence, it could lead to unsatisfactory location in embedding space. Of course if your text is long, this could be mitigated because most of the other words could carry the appropriate meaning. After you combine the embedding vector for all tokens together, the entire text embedding maybe not bad.